# Having image map problems in Firefox

Tags: image, firefox, html, dictionary

My image map is not working in Firefox, though it works in Chrome and Safari. I think it has to do with some of the tags being inside divs. Could you guys help me out as I don't know much about this:

```
<div style="font-size: 14px" id="tabs-1">
  ....
    <img src="/data/04_cvit/input.fa_x_Glyma1aaunq_gray.png" style="display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto" usemap="#CViT_image_gray"></img>
    <map name="#CViT_image_gray">
        <area onmouseover="mouseover_toggle('Glyma02g37330..173..179..694..700')" shape="rect" coords="173,694,179,700" href="http://soybase.org/gb2/gbrowse/gmax1.01/?start=42605601;stop=42707190;ref=Gm02;h_feat=Glyma02g37330@yellow" target="_blank"></area>
        <area onmouseover="mouseover_toggle('Glyma02g37330..1013..1019..723..729')" shape="rect" coords="1013,723,1019,729" href="http://soybase.org/gb2/gbrowse/gmax1.01/?start=44520215;stop=44621936;ref=Gm14;h_feat=Glyma14g35580@yellow" target="_blank"></area>
        <area onmouseover="mouseover_toggle('Glyma02g37330..313..319..147..153')" shape="rect" coords="313,147,319,153" href="http://soybase.org/gb2/gbrowse/gmax1.01/?start=6118288;stop=6218620;ref=Gm04;h_feat=Glyma04g07910@yellow" target="_blank"></area>  
    </map>

    <div id="Glyma02g37330..173..179..694..700" style="border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);background-color: rgb(239,237,233); z-index: 1; visibility: hidden; position: absolute; width: 250px; left: 394px; top: 774px;">
        <input type="button" name="closeDiv" value="Close" onclick="mouseover_toggle('Glyma02g37330..173..179..694..700')"></input>
        <br /> Query = Glyma02g37330 <br />Target = Glyma02g37330
        <br />Chromosome = Gm02 <br />Start = 42605601 <br />End = 42707190
        <br />
        <a href="http://soybase.org/gb2/gbrowse/gmax1.01/?start=42605601;stop=42707190;ref=Gm02;h_feat=Glyma02g37330@yellow">Click to view in GBrowse</a>
    </div>

    <div id="Glyma02g37330..1013..1019..723..729" style="border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);background-color: rgb(239,237,233); z-index: 1; visibility: hidden; position: absolute; width: 250px; left: 394px; top: 774px;">
        <input type="button" name="closeDiv" value="Close" onclick="mouseover_toggle('Glyma02g37330..1013..1019..723..729')"></input>
        <br /> Query = Glyma02g37330
        <br />Target = Glyma14g35580
        <br />Chromosome = Gm14
        <br />Start = 44520215
        <br />End = 44621936  <br />
        <a href="http://soybase.org/gb2/gbrowse/gmax1.01/?start=44520215;stop=44621936;ref=Gm14;h_feat=Glyma14g35580@yellow">Click to view in GBrowse</a>
    </div>

    <div id="Glyma02g37330..313..319..147..153" style="border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);background-color: rgb(239,237,233); z-index: 1; visibility: hidden; position: absolute; width: 250px; left: 394px; top: 774px;">
        <input type="button" name="closeDiv" value="Close" onclick="mouseover_toggle('Glyma02g37330..313..319..147..153')"></input>
        <br /> Query = Glyma02g37330
        <br />Target = Glyma04g07910
        <br />Chromosome = Gm04
        <br />Start = 6118288
        <br />End = 6218620
        <br />
        <a href="http://soybase.org/gb2/gbrowse/gmax1.01/?start=6118288;stop=6218620;ref=Gm04;h_feat=Glyma04g07910@yellow">Click to view in GBrowse</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Solution: 

apparently your map must be named name="MAPNAME" and in your <img> tag must use usemap="#MAPNAME". This is not required in google chrome but it is in firefox. Go figure.

Comment: You shouldn't put the solution in the question or comments. Put it down as an answer and mark it as accepted. People might then vote the answer up as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure your map name appears in both the MAP and IMG tag
like the following:

```
<map name="name123">...

<img src="yoururlhere" usemap="#name123">
```